# flex How to draw over an image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I would like to realize something simple (i thought!) but not. I would like to draw upon an image. I've create a new component DrawingImg, which extends s:Image

```
public class DrawingImg extends Image

{
    private var isDrawing:Boolean = false;
    private var x1:int;
    private var y1:int;
    private var x2:int;
    private var y2:int;

    public var drawColor:uint = 0x000000;

    public function DrawingImg()
    {
        super();

        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void {
            erase();
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            x1 = mouseX;
            y1 = mouseY;
            isDrawing = true;
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!event.buttonDown){
                isDrawing = false;
            }
            x2 = mouseX;
            y2 = mouseY;
            if (isDrawing){
                graphics.lineStyle(2, drawColor);
                graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
                graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
            }
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            isDrawing = false;
        });
    }

    public function erase():void  {
        graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0.00001);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
}
```

here's my view :

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="GiftCertificateView" 
actionBarVisible="false" xmlns:local="*">
<local:DrawingImg source="/assets/dessin.png"  width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:View>
```

It's "near" to work, when my mouse is out of the image, i can draw my line, but when i'm over the image, nothing appears ? 
Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot draw on the Spark Image with the graphics API. I haven't looked at the source lately, so I can't tell you exactly why.

A quick solution would be to make your `DrawingImg` class extend `UIComponent` instead of `Image`:

```
public class DrawingImage extends UIComponent
```

Now layer your drawing component on top of the Image in your View:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="GiftCertificateView" actionBarVisible="false" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:Image source="@Embed('Grand Prismatic Spring.jpg')" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <local:DrawingImg width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I've also tried with a class that extends "Group" and it works too.